# JavaFX how to make ScrollPane content grow horizontally when using FXML?

Tags: java, javafx

This is normal horizontal grow of my `GridPane`:
[image: Unwrapped]

But when i wrap `GridPane` in `ScrollPane`:
[image: Wrapped]

I would like to keep vertical scroll feature of `ScrollPane`, but allow my `GridPane` to grow horizontally in `ScrollPane`. Is it possible? I tried setting `HBar Policy` to `NEVER`, but it only hides HBar. Thanks in advance.

Minimal example in code (which seems working):

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setFitToHeight(true);
sp.setFitToWidth(true);
GridPane gp = new GridPane();
        
TextField tf1 = new TextField();
TextField tf2 = new TextField();
TextField tf3 = new TextField();
TextField tf4 = new TextField();

gp.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, 1000, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
gp.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, 1000, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
gp.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(10, 20, 1000, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
gp.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(10, 20, 1000, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
gp.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(10, 20, 1000, Priority.ALWAYS, VPos.CENTER, true));
        
gp.add(tf1, 0, 0);
gp.add(tf2, 1, 0);
gp.add(tf3, 0, 1);
gp.add(tf4, 0, 2);
        
sp.setContent(gp);
        
stage.setScene(new Scene(sp));
stage.show();
```

My example in FXML (which does not work):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<ScrollPane fitToHeight="true" fitToWidth="true" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <content>
      <GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" maxWidth="1000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="1000.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="1000.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="1000.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="20.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <TextField />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: Does doing `scrollPane.setFitWidth(true)` work?

Comment: @Slaw Both `.setFitWidth()` and `.setFitHeight()` are set to `true`, so no.

Comment: A [mre] would be useful.

Comment: @Slaw, it seems the OP has done the work to make their question more inline with SO standards. I guess you closed it. Can you consider undoing that please?

Comment: @julien.giband "I guess you closed it" – I'm not one of the three that voted to close (though I realize you can't see that yet, due to rep).

Comment: @Slaw sorry for the bother then, just tried to make a guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works this way if you set the `fitToWidth` property of your `ScrollPane` to `true`.

Of course your `GridPane` must be able to grow, so you need to make sure that its `prefWidth`/`maxWidth` properties don't prevent that, same for at least one of its columns.

Sample FXML (tested in SceneBuilder):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="410.0" prefWidth="518.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <content>
      <GridPane hgap="6.0" vgap="4.0">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints fillWidth="false" hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="300.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="150.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </content>
</ScrollPane>
```

Comment: Yeah, this was my problem. I set `maxWidth` to `USE_PREF_SIZE` in SceneBuilder, which results in adding `maxWidth="-Infinity"` in `GridPane` tag.